# How can I make responsive computer and touch click and drag?

Tags: unity, mobile, editors, clicker

This code works but it has a little delay on computer controls and higher delay on mobile touch screen controls, so its not responsive as I want it to be.

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    offset = transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, transform.position.y, 0.0f));
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, transform.position.y, 0.0f);
    transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(newPosition) + offset;
    transform.position = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, posXMin, posXMax), transform.position.y);
}
```

Comment: This code alone does not create a delay, so the lack of responsiveness is likely coming from somewhere else in your project.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to look into that. Thank you :)